Geometric Interpretation of Subset Sum Problem Solution
For $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $s_1, ..., s_n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $s_k \leq 2^m$. Consider the partition problem (a special case of the Subset Sum problem):
$$
\exists^? x \in \{0,1\}^n \hspace{0.5cm} \text{with} \hspace{0.5cm} S^T\cdot \left(x - \frac{1}{2} \cdot 1_{n\times 1}\right) = 0
$$ where $S = \begin{bmatrix} s_1 &... &s_n\end{bmatrix}^T$.
This can be interpreted, I think, as the problem of determining whether the hyperplane $S^T\cdot \left(x - \frac{1}{2} \cdot 1_{n\times 1}\right) = 0$ which passes through the center of the unit hypercube also passes through one of the hypercube vertices.

solution attempt
I stumbled upon the following approach: let $u_k \in \{1, ... , n^2\}$ with
$$
u_k = \left\lfloor n^2 \cdot \frac{s_k}{\|S\|} \right\rfloor
$$ then $U = \begin{bmatrix} u_1 &... &u_n\end{bmatrix}^T $ i.e. an approximation of the normal vector with elements written on less bits. Define
$$
c_a = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n u_k\cdot s_k}{\|U\| \cdot \|S\|} = \cos(a)
$$ the angle cosine between $U, S$. For a solution $P$ of the original partition problem, (i.e. a vertex of the unit hypercube on the hyperplane $S^T\cdot \left( x - \frac{1}{2} \cdot 1_{n \times 1}\right) = 0$ ) let $P'$ be the projection on the hyperplane $U^T\cdot \left( x - \frac{1}{2} \cdot 1_{n \times 1}\right) = 0$ (with red in figure), also a central hyperplane passing through the cube center, but with $U$ as normal vector. One can easily see that
$$
d = \|P'-P\| = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2} \cdot \sin(a) = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2} \cdot \sqrt{1 - c_a^2}
$$ It follows that $P$ (the original solution) should belong to a translation (with green in figure, either forward or backwards of the hyperplane $U^T\cdot \left( x - \frac{1}{2} \cdot 1_{n \times 1}\right) = 0$ ) along its normal direction, with exactly $d$. Therefore for each solution $P$ of the original problem, it must also be the solution of the following problem:
$$
\exists^?x\in \{0,1\}^n \hspace{0.5cm} \text{with} \hspace{0.5cm} U^T\cdot \left( x - \left( \frac{1}{2}\cdot 1_{n \times 1} \pm \frac{U}{\|U\|} \cdot d \right)\right) = 0
$$ The later problem is equivalent to
$$
U^T\cdot x = T 
$$ where $T = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n u_k}{2} \pm d \cdot \|U\| $which (because the elements of $U$ are written on at most $\mathcal{O}(\log(m))$ bits) can be solved with dynamical programming. Basically a negative answer to these two problems would prove the non-existence of a solution to the initial partition problem.
question
This is at least true in $2-d$. Could we scale this to higher dimensions?
